# How to initialize another WebElement inside the method in Java with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm a bit concerned with the minor problem that I'm facing. I have a test case where I need to pick up any value from the drop down. After selection entire web page reloads and I have 2 options. If warning message appears, I need to click on drop down again and choose another value. If warning message doesn't appear, just click on "Continue" button. All my values inside the drop down have the same id which only differs in ending:

```
uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_1
uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_2
uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_3
uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_4
```

till 30. What I did I called Random class where I set up variable from 1 - 30

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(30) + 1;
```

Now I look for my element this way

```
WebElement valueFromDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_" + x));
```

But if warning message appears and I need to click on another value, my code picks up the same value over and over. The question is how to correctly and with less code writing click on another element in drop down? The full class looks like this

```
    public class SomeClassName{

        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(30) + 1;
        @FindBy(xpath = "someXpathExpression") private WebElement dropDown;
        @FindBy(xpath = "someXpathExpression") private WebElement warningMessage;
        @FindBy(xpath = "someXpathExpression") private WebElement continueButton;

public void fillForm() throws Exception{
    WebElement valueFromDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_" + x));
    dropDown.click();
    valueFromDropDown.click();
    if(user will see that warningMessage suddenly apppears){
    dropDown.click();
    valueFromDropDown.click(); -> this is where I want to click on another value
    }else{
    contunieButton.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a method to return drop down webelement randomly like below

```
public WebElement getDropDownValueRandomly() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt(30) + 1;
    WebElement valueFromDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_" + x));

    return valueFromDropDown;

}
```

Your Class will be like :

```
public class SomeClassName{

    @FindBy(xpath = "someXpathExpression") private WebElement dropDown;
    @FindBy(xpath = "someXpathExpression") private WebElement warningMessage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "someXpathExpression") private WebElement continueButton;

public void fillForm() throws Exception{
    WebElement valueFromDropDown = getDropDownValueRandomly();
    dropDown.click();
    valueFromDropDown.click();
    if(user will see that warningMessage suddenly apppears){
    dropDown.click();
    getDropDownValueRandomly().click(); -> this is where I want to click on another value
    }else{
    contunieButton.click();
    }
}

public WebElement getDropDownValueRandomly() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt(30) + 1;
    WebElement valueFromDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_" + x));

    return valueFromDropDown;

}
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: @Rama getDropDownValueRandomly method name cannot be clicked.